# why does the app crash in device but runs in emulator?

Tags: android, crash, emulation, classnotfoundexception, telephony

I uninstalled and installed the app on my device and it started to crash. 
Here is the logcat

```
E/Xposed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneSubInfo#getDeviceId()#exact
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findMethodExact(XposedHelpers.java:341)
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(XposedHelpers.java:182)
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(XposedHelpers.java:257)
                                           at com.vivek.imeichangerpro.XposedIMEIChanger.handleLoadPackage(XposedIMEIChanger.java:108)
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage$Wrapper.handleLoadPackage(IXposedHookLoadPackage.java:34)
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.call(XC_LoadPackage.java:61)
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XCallback.callAll(XCallback.java:106)
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedInit$2.beforeHookedMethod(XposedInit.java:116)
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:314)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(<Xposed>)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                           at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

03-24 15:15:29.833 19472-19472/? E/Xposed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneSubInfo#getDeviceId()#exact
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findMethodExact(XposedHelpers.java:330)
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(XposedHelpers.java:182)
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(XposedHelpers.java:257)
                                               at com.magic.imeichanger.XposedIMEIChanger.handleLoadPackage(XposedIMEIChanger.java:38)
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage$Wrapper.handleLoadPackage(IXposedHookLoadPackage.java:34)
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.call(XC_LoadPackage.java:61)
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XCallback.callAll(XCallback.java:106)
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedInit$2.beforeHookedMethod(XposedInit.java:116)
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:314)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication()
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1408)
                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
03-24 15:15:29.877 19472-19472/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.seven.pprs.bloodlink, PID: 19472
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.seven.pprs.bloodlink/com.seven.pprs.bloodlink.LaunchActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.seven.pprs.bloodlink.LaunchActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.seven.pprs.bloodlink-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.seven.pprs.bloodlink-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                       at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.seven.pprs.bloodlink.LaunchActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.seven.pprs.bloodlink-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.seven.pprs.bloodlink-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                       at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102) 
                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.seven.pprs.bloodlink.LaunchActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/dalvik-cache/xposed_XResourcesSuperClass.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                            ... 13 more
                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.seven.pprs.bloodlink.LaunchActivity
                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                ... 14 more
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: What is the device and version you are using? Seems like an expected method getDeviceId() is not found on your phone. Is it an undocumented API?

Comment: Device: OnePlus One
Android version: 6.0.1